# JSR303 Validation: Two (or more) Validations constraints: After first returned an error, do not evaluate second?

Tags: java, validation, javabeans, bean-validation

given the following two Constraints

```
@NotNull
@Pattern (pattern="foobar")
private String myFooBarMember;
```

Is there a possibility, if the first one matched (=returned an error) (@NotNull) to not evaluate the second one (@Pattern)? or does JSR303 always evaluate all  Constraints? If there is a possibility to not evaluate the second after a first match, please state how this can be done.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest to use `group` parameter for this: when one of constraints in group fails, other will not evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not a JSR 303 specialist, but I've found the following excerpts from the [1.0 FR](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/):

> **2.3. Constraint composition**
>
> Note:
>
> If a composing constraint fails and if the composed constraint is
>   marked as `@ReportAsSingleViolation`, the Bean Validation provider is
>   free to not process the other composing constraints for this composed
>   constraint.

and:

> **3.5. Validation routine**
>
> - for all reachable fields, **execute all field level validations** (including the ones expressed on superclasses) matching the targeted
>     group unless the given validation constraint has already been
>     processed during this validation routine for a given navigation path
>     (see Section 3.5.1) as part of a previous group match.

So from the latter, I'd say that by default all validators will be executed.

From the former, I'd say that this (constraint composition) would be one way to achieve what you want. Although it might (and probably is) dependent on the Bean Validation implementor, so you'd need to read some proprietary docs.